# Populate Lookup Field with Record Created From Trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am trying to create a trigger that does the following:

1. Once an Account has been created, create an unrelated record (called a "Portal Content" record) that bears the same name, assuming the default RecordTypeId
2. Take the ID of the newly created "Portal Content" record, and insert it into a lookup field on the originally created Account

My current code does item 1 successfully, but when I added new code to complete item 2, I received the following error:

```
Line: 6, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: 
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, newAccountCreated: execution of 
AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only 
Trigger.newAccountCreated: line 12, column 1: []
```

My current trigger is as follows:

```
trigger newAccountCreated on Account (after insert) {

    List<Account> alist = Trigger.New;

    for(Account a : alist) {

        if (a.RecordTypeId == '012i0000001Iy1H') {
//            system.debug(a.Name);
            Portal_Content__c p = new Portal_Content__c(Name=a.Name,School_SFDC_ID__c=a.Id);
            insert p;

            a.Portal_Content_Record__c = p.Id;
            update a;
        }
    }

}
```

I do not understand why the the error message states that the "Record is read only," or how to amend this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the same record on an 'after' trigger, it must be done on a before trigger; change to:

```
trigger newAccountCreated on Account (before insert) {
```

Comment: I made this change and received the following error `System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old`

Comment: also remove the "update a;" line. since you're now changing the value in the 'before' trigger it'll modify that value for you when the trigger ends.

Comment: I created a followup question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895541/connecting-unrelated-objects-during-apex-trigger) if you are interested